# undefined reference to Mysnprintf

Tags: c++, codeblocks

am using `CodeBlocks` and am trying to make a hook dll so inside

`DllMain`

```
#include "main.h"
#include "Asm.h"
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
    static HINSTANCE WINAPI Mysnprintf(char* str, int len, const char* format, ...);

    static void InitDll(){
        Originalsnprintf = (snprintfFn)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("msvcr90.dll"), "_snprintf");
        Asm code;
        code.JMP((int)Mysnprintf); // where JMP = Asm& JMP(int address){...}
    }
```

I have no clue what's wrong since if I did the same with `Microsoft Visual C++` it will work with no errors!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker tells you the function is *undefined*, and it's right. You have not written a *definition* for your function. You've merely *declared* it.

Put some curly braces after the function and tell your compiler what you want that function to *do*:

```
static HINSTANCE WINAPI Mysnprintf(char* str, int len, const char* format, ...)
{
  ...
}
```